# how to close all view controllers that presented modally inFront of each other with unwind segue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller, unwind-segue, dismissviewcontroller

so I have a main view controller that the view controllers will present inFront of each other and I want when user click the button in the last view controller close all of the presented modally view controllers so I used this code But I didn't get the result

```
let destination = matchViewController()
let appDelegate:UIApplicationDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate!
let initialViewController = destination
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
appDelegate.window??.rootViewController = navigationController
appDelegate.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I want to use unwind segue to exit But there is another problem too 
the last view controller will present many times in many different situations so I just to dismiss all presented modally view controllers in. this situation 
I rather not using the navigationController But if I had to use it pleas tell me where exactly should I use that ?

Answer (score 0):

**Two options:**

1. Dismiss all view controllers on the root view controller

   ```
   self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
2. Dismiss all viewControllers until it has a `presentingController`

   ```
   func dismissAllControllers() {

       guard let vc = self.presentingViewController else { return }

       while (vc.presentingViewController != nil) {
           vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: the Dismiss all viewControllers until it has a presentingController how this work?

Comment: You need to call this on last view controller button action

Comment: ok there is a problem there some view controllers in main page and before that and I don't want to dismiss them too I just want to dismiss view controllers until showing mainViewController

Comment: you can add a check on `mainViewController` in while loop

Comment: I can't do that the Xcode won't allow me to do that